# Syntax error in wget request to https://drive.google.com/

Tags: python-3.x, image, google-chrome, encryption, wget

I am getting a syntax error in this request:

```
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png"
```

How to remove this error?

> error:File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/arnoldmap/arnold map.py", line 9, in 
> from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

I google but I am not getting proper syntax of this.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import random
from math import log
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow   # error on this line

from tqdm import tqdm
import wget
# Downloading HorizonZero.png
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm 
mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png"

# Downloading lena.bmp
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=19xZhsjs_r0tLwtu_Wl5DB5rG26dhw069 
mv uc?id=19xZhsjs_r0tLwtu_Wl5DB5rG26dhw069 lena.bmp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/wget/

Either calling inside a batch script:

```
python -m wget [options] <URL>
```

or inside a python script:

```
filename = wget.download("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png")
```

Comment: okay how to move like in coloba its !mv but in pycharm? what is the syntax

Comment: The same as you would do it inside a python script/file:

wget.download("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png")

Comment: hey i do installed  module named 'google.colab' still i am getting error File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/arnoldmap/arnold map.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

Comment: Then please mark my answer as accepted answer for others to clarify. You were using python 2 syntax here.
for your second question i would need more details, but i am sure you fill find answers via google for this. I guess the module is named differently

Comment: see i made the changes i m using python 3.6 and have installed package import cv2 still getting this error plz help thank you

Comment: I am not getting the same result after i installed google colab and tried the same thing.
Uninstall the package and install again. If this does't help google your request or open up another question. Comments are not meant for this!